# Dropdown Do Menu Bootstrap Não Desce

Tags: bootstrap, dropdown

Me desculpa voltar ao assunto de dropdown do Bootstrap, mas já vi todas as perguntas relacionadas e não consegui resolver meu problema.

Não entendo quase nada de JavaScript, e estou usando a versão mais nova do Bootstrap (versão 4).

O console do navegador está apresentando os seguintes erros:
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
bootstrap.min.js:sourcemap:6 Uncaught ReferenceError: Popper is not defined
bootstrap.js:3849 Uncaught ReferenceError: Popper is not defined

Meu menu código HTML:

@ViewBag.Title

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <img height="110" src="~/Content/Imagens/Logo-Prefeitura-De-Araguaina (1).png" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6" style="margin-top: 1em;">
        <h2>Gestor Rodoviário de Araguaína</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 d-md-flex justify-content-md-end" style="margin-top: 1em;">
        <p>Olá, @Session["nomeUsuario"]!</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 d-md-flex justify-content-md-end col-lg-12 d-lg-flex justify-content-lg-end" style="margin-top: -1.5em;">
        <a style="margin-top: -3em;" href="@Url.Action("Logout", "Usuario")">sair</a>
    </div>
</div>







<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    Dropdown
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                </div>
            </li>
            @*<li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
            </li>*@
        </ul>
        @*<form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
            <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>*@
    </div>
</nav>

<script>
      $(function () {
        $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();
      });
</script>


<script type="text/javascript" src="~/scripts/js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/scripts/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/scripts/js/bootstrap.js"></script>


<div>
    @RenderBody()
</div>
```

Comment: Cara dei uma olhada na documentação do Bootstrap4 e não vi nada de referenciar jQuery para funcionar o dropdown no menu. Já tentou funcionar sem o jQuery? Pois este erro no console se refere ao jQuery.

Comment: Leandro, tirei o jQuery e mesmo assim não funcionou.

Comment: tentou colocar o jquery no cabeçalho ao invés de deixar no rodapé? Jogue ele e o bootstrap.min pra cima e teste de novo

Comment: Já tentei Darlei. Nada de funcionar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pela mensagem de erro, e por utilizar o Bootstrap 4, lhe falta o popper.js:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.6/popper.min.js"></script>
```

E você está adicionando o bootstrap.js duas vezes ? adicione apenas o `'.min'`.

Referência: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46952775/bootstrap-4-uncaught-referenceerror-popper-is-not-defined

Comment: AnthraxisBR, deixei apenas o bootstrap.min e coloquei a referencia ao popper.js, mas continua sem funcionar.
Está dando os seguintes erros:
ListaLinhas:79 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
bootstrap.min.js:6 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
popper.min.js:4 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token export

Comment: Ja tentou usar o bundle em vez de importar as bibliotecas separadas ?

Comment: Desculpa a ignorância, mas o que seria um Bundle?

Comment: @DiegoGrossi é o arquivo que inclui tudo de uma vez. ele vem junto quando você baixa o bootstrap

Comment: AnthraxisBR, coloquei toda a pasta do Bootstrap e deu certo! Agora não entendi o porquê, já que independente se jogo toda a pasta ou só o que preciso, os arquivos que estou chamando são sempre os mesmos.

Comment: Se tiver curiosidade, pegue os arquivos, faça um mapinha, pegue o código que importou, e faça um nova pergunta, provavelmente alguém vai saber te dizer!

Comment: Valeu AnthraxisBR! O importante é que funcionou!